# Moving files from directory and all subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a command that list all files in the directory and subdirectories? For example, when I am cleaning out my `~/Download` directory, I would like to move all the movie files to a specific directory.

If I try this:

```
mv *.avi Directory
```

the avi files in subdirectories will not be moved. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `find` command, e.g.:

```
find  ~/Download -name \*.avi -exec mv "{}" Directory \;
```

Comment: This makes a list of all the avi files, which is helpful. But is there a way to directly move them somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: @SolalAmouyal Yes, I have updated the answer with the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Hey, it's been a while but can you explain the meaning of of the strings " "{}" " and "\;"? Also, does "-exec" work with every command?

Comment: @SolalAmouyal, `{}` is replaced by the pathname of the current file (e.g. file1.avi, file2.avi, etc. in this case) and regarding `\;` the `find` command expects a semicolon (`;`) to terminate the expression used with the `-exec` parameter, but since a semicolon is used to separate commands in the shell it must be escaped to avoid shell's default handling of such characters.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find` like this:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -exec mv "{}" Directory \;
```

You should run this command in your `~/Download` directory (or replace the dot with another source directory name). The string between `-exec` and `\;` will be executed as a normal shell command for every matched file with filename substituted for `{}`.

Comment: +1 your correct answer came first but then the accepted one added the `mv` part.